# How do you "convert" $('#yourname').val(); to vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript

Just need help getting the vanilla javascript version of `$('#yourname').val();` part of `var name=$('#yourname').val();`

Comment: `document.querySelector("#yourname").value` / `document.getElementById("yourname").value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous selectors of JavaScript in order to do this.

You can find some [here](https://www.w3schools.com/w3js/w3js_selectors.asp), [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp), and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>

    <style>

    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="hidden" id="someID" value="625413">
    <script>
        var a = document.getElementById("someID").value;
        var b = $("#someID").val();
        var c = document.querySelector("#someID").value;
        alert(a + " / " + b + " / " + c);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

`var a = document.getElementById("someID").value;` is the 'classic' example of Vanilla JavaScript.